# How to insert data field with apostrophe

Tags: php

I have an insert statement where I am already taking two fields from a csv and combining them to one record in my database as a string. The problem now is that some of the fields have an apostrophe such as the name O'Brien.

The stops at the first record with this so I am trying to figure out how to ignor the apostrophe.

```
$compname = $data[4] . ' ' . $data[5];

"INSERT into gaa_ccinvoices_contacts(id,name,contact,email,contact_note) values('$data[3]','". $compname ."','". $compname ."','$data[6]','". $compname ."')";
```

Comment: Use a prepared statement; it will help make your code more secure, and if you're importing data from a CSV, it's more efficient, too

Comment: Yea I am just going to change all of his code to PDO, on an easy note I just found that $data[4] = str_replace("'",'',$data[4]);   will just remove them all together

Comment: You can replace O'Brien and use O''Brien.

str_replace("'","''",$data[4]);

Comment: why remove or replace? just escape them,  functions in linked code